# twitter not open on phonegap android childbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, twitter, childbrowser

I am creating a app in which i required to open a twiiter feed page.
I used a chilbrowser plugin with cordova cordova-1.7.0.js
Link which i use on childbrowser to open is twitter feed link.
https://mobile.twitter.com/pixtv
I tried different link in same chilbrowser they works fine only this twitter is not opening.

**Thanks and Regards**

Answer (score 4):

Try to open a intent follow page as this one:
http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=pixtv

Remember to whitelisting this page on config.xml file as follow:

```
<gap:plugin name="ChildBrowser" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=pixtv"/>
```

No fullstop on access origin and no htpps on the URL.
Hope this helps, K.